# How to highlight particular menu item onclick hyperlink in menubar in php

Tags: php

I am trying to include my pages in `header.php` file , But I need the list-item to have a class of `active`. The Menu is in `header.php` and currently looks like this:-

```
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#">Help Desk No</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a title="City Level" href="City-Help.php">City Level</a></li>
    <li><a title="State Level" href="State-Help.php">State Level</a></li>
    <li><a title="India Level" href="India-Help.php">India Level</a></li>
    <li><a title="World Level" href="World-Help.php">World Level</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

what I do :-define variable `$page=basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); in header.php` page and for other pages change the variable value according to the page name but it have follow only one sub menu, how it is possible for 2,3,4 sub menus.

```
<li class="dropdown <?php echo ($page == "City-Help.php" ? "active" : "")?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

Edited answer after @Kumar's comment

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="btn dropdown-toggle <?php echo ($page == "City-Help.php" 
OR $page == "State-Help.php" OR $page == "India-Help.php" 
OR $page == "World-Help.php") ? "active" : "";?>" data-toggle="dropdown">Help Desk No</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a title="City Level" href="City-Help.php" >City Level</a></li>
    <li><a title="State Level" href="State-Help.php">State Level</a></li>
    <li><a title="India Level" href="India-Help.php">India Level</a></li>
    <li><a title="World Level" href="World-Help.php">World Level</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

and make sure that you put the php code `$page=basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);` before the menu mark-up.

P.S. I added a .btn class to the first `<a>` tag, since I guess that you are using bootstrap and in bootstrap, for an ordinary link being active or not has no visual difference.

Comment: I want to highlight <a href="#">`Help Desk No`</a> in every sub menu clicks.

Answer (score 0):

After Searching, Finally I Got the Solution :-

```
<?php $activePage = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], ".php"); ?>  


<li class="dropdown <?php  if($activePage=='City-Help'){echo 'active';}elseif($activePage =='State-Help'){echo 'active';}else{echo 'noactive';} ; ?>">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" title="Help Desk No">Help Desk No</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a title="City Level" href="City-Help.php">City Level</a></li>
    <li><a title="State Level" href="State-Help.php">State Level</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```